# Purple Screen of Death after changing Nvidia X Server prime profile to Performance mode

Tags: boot, drivers, 20.04, nvidia, graphics

For an Edge AI system I'm using an AMD Ryzen 5 5600G based compute platform with a NVIDIA Tesla T4 for the AI workloads.

After setting the NVIDIA X Server Prime profile from "NVIDIA on demand" to "NVIDIA Performance Mode" (not knowing was it does tbh, I was blinded by a the word performance) and rebooting, I was greeted with a purple screen of death on my Ubuntu 20.04.
Removing the GPU solved the issue but here I was not able to undo the change in settings or resolve the issue otherwise. When plugging the GPU back in, the purple screen returns on startup.

Does someone has any tips on how to solve this? E.g. resetting all NVIDIA X Server settings somehow? I was not able to find any guide on how to do that.

Thx a lot!

BR
Kevin

Comment: Did you disabled Secure Boot or signed the Nvidia drivers properly?

Comment: @ChanganAuto yes. The system also ran  for 3 months without a problem. Only after enabling this setting it caused the issue...

Comment: And it still runs if the iGPU is selected, probably. What you did was selecting the Nvidia (dGPU) instead and then the problem manifested where it shouldn't.

Comment: You probably installed the wrong Nvidia drivers version. And by "you" I mean either you manually or the system's. According to Nvidia a Tesla T4 in Linux should NOT run with the latest version which is typically what the installer chooses but with the 440 branch.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all NVIDIA packages.

1. Remove all the nvidia packages.

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade
   sudo apt autoremove
   sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
   sudo apt-get remove --purge "nvidia*"
   ```
2. If you have added an Nvidia PPA to `/etc/apt/sources.list` remove that PPA by prefacing its line in sources.list with a `#` to comment it out. Run `sudo apt update` to refresh the list of available software.
3. Reboot with `sudo reboot`

Optionally you can reinstall the recommended NVIDIA proprietary graphics drivers after they have been removed. The `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` command  installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install && sudo reboot
```